# How to check the latest value from a column and generate a new row with that certain value+1?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am finding it difficult figuring out how to auto-generate the column ID for every Recipe created by the API. At this point, if I want to create a new row in the Recipe table, I have to insert an ID by myself, otherwise, it will just be assigned to 0. I am looking for a way to check the latest ID already existant in the database and when a new entry is created, its ID will be the latest ID + 1.

**RecipeController** from the API

```
        [Route("v1/recipe")]
    [HttpPost()]
    public IActionResult CreateList([FromBody]Recipe recipe)
    {
        try
        {
            if (recipe == null) throw new ArgumentException("No data specified");
            //if (recipe.Name == null) throw new ArgumentException("No name specified");

            using (var con = _connFactory())
            {
                con.Open();
                con.Execute(@"INSERT INTO dbo.Recipe (Id, Name, RecipeLink, Category1Id ,Category2Id, Category3Id, Category4Id, RecipeById,
                            TotalTime, TotalTimeUnitId, ActiveTime, ActivetimeUnitId, Instructions, SourceKey, RecipeBy, InsertedAtUtc, IsVerified, NumPersons) 
                            VALUES (@id, @name, @recipeLink, @category1Id, @category2Id, @category3Id, @category4Id, @recipeById,
                            @totalTime, @totalTimeUnitId, @activeTime, @activeTimeUnitId, @instructions, @sourceKey, @recipeBy, getutcdate(), @isVerified, @numPersons)",
                            new
                            {
                                recipe.id,
                                recipe.name,
                                recipe.recipeLink,
                                recipe.category1Id,
                                recipe.category2Id,
                                recipe.category3Id,
                                recipe.category4Id,
                                recipe.recipeById,
                                recipe.totalTime,
                                recipe.totalTimeUnitId,
                                recipe.activeTime,
                                recipe.activeTimeUnitId,
                                recipe.instructions,
                                recipe.sourceKey,
                                recipe.recipeBy,
                                recipe.isVerified,
                                recipe.numPersons
                            });
            }
            return Ok(recipe);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

**RecipeController** from the MVC

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(Recipe recipe)
    {
        if (recipe.id == 0)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.client.PostAsJsonAsync("", recipe).Result;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.client.PutAsJsonAsync(recipe.id.ToString(), recipe).Result;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: You should let the database handle the creation of an ID with an Identity column.

Comment: _"I have to insert an ID by myself, otherwise, it will just be assigned to 0."_ - why? Just set up an identity column and don't include `Id` in your list of columns.

Comment: As @VDWWD said, You can set the id column with identity and set increment to 1. You don't even need to include id column in insert statement.Database will take care of it for you

Comment: I thought of letting the database handle the creation of an ID but the database isn't really mine so I was looking for a solution without actually having to alter something in the db. But thanks for the hints! @jarlh - SSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use an identity field, you can get the highest current ID like this:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.Recipe
```

You can either do it in a separate query, or embed it into your insert:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Recipe (Id, Name,...)
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM dbo.Recipe), @name, …)
```

If you use a separate query, you should use a transaction and table lock in case two people try to create rows at the same time.

Comment: You will still need to add 1 to the MAX(ID) before inserting

Comment: But make sure you take a tablelock for the duration of the select and insert, else you might add the same id multiple times.

Comment: A transaction doesn't stop 2 connections reading the max concurrently. Only a table lock does.

Comment: This tool will only be used by 1 person at a time, I suppose. Either way, the chances are very slim that 2 persons will try to add a recipe at the same time to worry about concurrent transactions. Would you suggest that I'd still look into table locking, even in this case?

Comment: @Questieme - for a recipe book used by one person, there's no need. However if you're doing this to learn how to write business applications then locking and concurrency is something you'll need to understand.